# How to render a partial in the main project from an area in MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, partial-views, asp.net-mvc-areas

I have a MVC 3 Razor project.  It has an area called Admin.  I have the basic layout of the page in the project's Views/Shared folder (by default).  I have a controller in the main project called Common.  It will be in charge of certain parts of the layout that are based on business logic (navigation based upon roles, etc.).  I have

`@Html.Action("Navigation", "Common")`

being called in the _layout.cshtml file.  That is set to render the nav bar.  When I go to a route in the Admin area ("admin/somedomainobject/add"), a run time error states the following:

> "The controller for path
>   "/admin/somedomainobject/add" was not
>   found or does not implement
>   IController."

It exists just fine, when I remove the line from the layout.  The error is happening if I use the above syntax or the following:

```
@{Html.RenderAction("Naviation", "Common");}
```

Is it because I am using areas?  Am I utilizing the main project folders the wrong way?

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is because in your admin area all generated links will inherit this area unless explicitly told otherwise, try

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("Naviation", "Common", new { @area = string.Empty }); }
```